# Linking actions to menu bar in PyQt from Qt Designer

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer, signals-slots

I'm new to QT Designer and PyQt, but I seem to be trying to do something either too simple to be mentioned or too rare!

I created a simple window using QT Designer. In that window there is two menu options; one should close the window, the other should open another window.

I converted the ui into a python file with the pyuic5 command.

This is the code I get:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'Win1.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.7
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(441, 305)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 441, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuClosing = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuClosing.setObjectName("menuClosing")
        self.menuOpen_Win_2 = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuOpen_Win_2.setObjectName("menuOpen_Win_2")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuClosing.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuOpen_Win_2.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.menuClosing.triggered['QAction*'].connect(MainWindow.close) # type: ignore
        self.menuOpen_Win_2.triggered['QAction*'].connect(MainWindow.open) # type: ignore
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.menuClosing.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Closing"))
        self.menuOpen_Win_2.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Open Win #2"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

New in QT Designer I have assigned the "close()" slot to Closing and I created a new slot "open()" that I linked to Open Win #2.

Obviously, neither work.

It seems there is a different logic than there is when assigning functions to submenus (where linking close() to it does work).

Does anyone knows how I should go about to do this?

Comment: In your code there's no trace of the connection to the "slots" you mentioned. Please provide a valid [mre].

Comment: This *is* the code generated by pyuic5 when used on the .ui that had the slots I mentioned. But if they aren't actually generated from Qt Designer, that might explain a few things.

Comment: @musicamante This seems to be what adding the slots add to the code: 
self.menubar.addAction(self.menuClosing.menuAction())
self.menubar.addAction(self.menuOpen_Win_2.menuAction())

Comment: Those are not slots. Those are just lines that add actions (representing menus) to the menubar. If I understand correctly, you want to add an action to the menubar that, once clicked directly calls a function instead of opening the relative menu; if that's the case, you cannot do that directly from Designer (besides, while it's possible, it's a bit uncommon, and generally discouraged as it's unintuitive). That must be done by code (similarly to what suggested in the deleted answer written by Alexander, but directly using an action, not a menu).

Comment: @musicamante Then I don't know where the Qt Designer custom slots went .... Anyway, could You provide a working example of how it could be done? I can't figure out how to link menubar to a function.

Comment: Can you please explain what you did to connect those slots? As far as I know, that's actually *not* possible, because Designer doesn't provide direct access to a menu action.

Comment: @musicamante Just like this:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/Pwus8qCfP5uox8JG9
with "open()" being a created slot.

Comment: I just noticed I had an older script. Doing the links in QT Designer actually added "self.menuClosing.triggered['QAction*'].connect(MainWindow.close) # type: ignore
        self.menuOpen_Win_2.triggered['QAction*'].connect(MainWindow.open) # type: ignore"
I'm gonna edit the code to add it.

Comment: @AdEp Those connections you created in the Signal/Slot Editor dialog apply to a QMenu, not a QAction. The `triggered` signal will only be emitted when a menu-item is activated (which your menus do not have). Qt Designer only supports adding actions to menus, not to the menubar itself. What you're trying to do must therefore be implemented in code, rather than via Qt Designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Designer doesn't allow to add basic actions to a QMenuBar.

In fact, both the "Edit Signals/Slots" mode and the "Signal/Slot Editor" only allow interacting with *widgets*: QActions are **not** widgets.

The only way to achieve this is by code, and by directly adding a *real* QAction to the menubar.

Remove those (probably empty) menus from the UI, rebuild the code with `pyuic` and then do something like this after (assuming that the output file is named `win1.py`):

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from win1 import Ui_MainWindow
from win2 import Ui_MainWindow2

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.closeAction = QtWidgets.QAction('Closing', self)
        self.menuBar().addAction(self.closeAction)
        self.openWin2Action = QtWidgets.QAction('Open Win #2', self)
        self.menuBar().addAction(self.openWin2Action)

        self.closeAction.triggered.connect(self.close)
        self.openWin2Action.triggered.connect(self.openWin2)

    def openWin2(self):
        self.win2 = Window2()
        self.win2.show()


class Window2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow2):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Notes:

- the code you provided is a `pyuic` output, which, in case you didn't know, must *never* be directly used or edited, if not for debugging or studying purposes; the above code uses the common practice of multiple inheritance as explained in the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html);
- I also faced the disappearing slot connection you mentioned, which is probably a Designer bug (there's no trace of the connection in the `.ui` file, so it's not a `pyuic` fault);
- even ignoring the above possible bug, the connection wouldn't have worked anyway: the [`triggered`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#triggered) signal of QMenu (similarly to [that of QMenuBar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenubar.html#triggered)) is emitted only when one of *its actions* is triggered (not the action of the menu itself);
- while I can understand the basic idea, using an action in a menubar is normally discouraged as counter-intuitive from the UX perspective; the convention says that users always expect a menu to be shown after clicking on a menu bar item (after all, it's called a "menu bar": a *bar of menus*): even if the action text is sufficiently verbose, the user cannot know that clicking on a "menu title" would actually trigger an action as final as closing a window; for what they know, that could just be a menu that shows possible options of closing (i.e. close without saving);
- the above code assumes that you also did create another main window in designer and also changed its object name to `MainWindow2`; while you could do `from win2 import Ui_MainWindow as Ui_MainWindow2`, it's good practice to set unique object names of top level windows: the output of `pyuic` will always be `Ui_<objectNameOfTopLevelWindow>`;
- in the comment of the deleted answer you mentioned that "closing like this seems to keep the Kernel running"; you're probably using an IDE or an interactive shell, which could ignore the default behavior (quitting the QApplication as soon as the last window is closed): running the script as stand-alone won't normally cause that, but you can always consider connecting to the [`QApplication.quit`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#quit) signal;

Comment: Great! This actually works (but I had to use QtWidgets.QMainwindow for some reason), but is there any way to insert new menu options in-between options created with Qt Designer ? (Like I have a "File" and an "Help" drop-down menu options, but I would like to have "Open Win2" in-between, because by convention "Help" would go on the right.)
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AdEp Sorry about that typo, I corrected the post (I imported the submodule, not the classes, so the `QtWidgets.` prefix is necessary). About your second question, use `insertAction(before, action)`, with `before` corresponding to the menu action *before* you want to insert the action: supposing that your "Help" menu is called `menuHelp` in Designer, use `self.menuBar().insertAction(self.menuHelp.menuAction(), self.openWin2Action)`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
self.ActionName.triggered.connect(self.onFunctionName)
```

where
ActionName - action/ menu item, created in QtDesigner, and onFunctionName - function/ method, processing menu/toolbar button-click event